# Using COM port in C# and not getting all sent data

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, serial-port

Just to explain, I have a dev board that is, on command, shooting out 4 chars (Bytes). The terminal program (RealTerm) i'm using to debug this sees all 4 bytes. I've now moved on to writing the desktop software, and my program is only paying attention to 1 out of 4 bytes sent. TO clarify, i don't know which 1 of 4 bytes (first , last, middle two) but i can find out if its really necessary.

At first I thought the SerialPort.DataReceived event would fire for each byte that was received. This isn't true, I don't know what causes it to fire but its not the receiving of a singular Byte.

So I tried looping over SerialPort.BytesToRead, but this also only gets the first byte, even though it recognizes there are 3 bytes to read (why not 4??)

Its not essential for me to receive this data at the exact time it hits the port, but obviously I dot want to be loosing 3/4 of my data. However it wont always be 4 bytes, that's just what its doing now. I just want to get all bytes that are ready to be read.

Event Handler:

```
private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (comPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                RxString = comPort.ReadExisting();
                RxByte = comPort.ReadByte(); 
                byte[] myByte = new byte[6];

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    myByte[i] = 0000000;
                }

                comPort.Read(myByte, 0, comPort.BytesToRead);
                for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
                {
                    if (myByte[i] != null)
                    {
                        thisBytes.Add(myByte[i]);
                    }
                }
                RxString = RxByte + "";
                try
                {
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(dealWithByte));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }


private void dealWithByte(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (byte item in thisBytes)
            {
                RxByte = Convert.ToInt16(item);
                string binary = Convert.ToString(RxByte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                //processTime(binary);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Well, the code is very broken.  Mixing ReadExisting() and Read() is bad, not paying attention to the return value of Read() is bad, hoping that you'll get all bytes is bad.  No clue what this is supposed to do but if you want 4 bytes then call ReadByte() 4 times.

Comment: Yes, i'm starting to get the feeling i'm an awful, awful programmer. Thanks for your answer though. However it want always be 4 bytes, that's just what its doing now. I just want to get all bytes that are ready to be read. I'll edit that into the first post.

Comment: I think people might be better off if Microsoft hadn't bundled a serial port class with .NET, since it's pretty badly broken.  I suggest finding a better library ASAP.  Even p/invoking the Win32 serial port functions would be easier in the long run.

Comment: If the Baud rate is low, the bytes may be arriving a bit later than your ReadExisiting executed.  You may want to  put a delay after received event fired and then read all.. you could get all 4 of them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a C# person but the code is pretty simple, pseudo code

```
    numBytes As Int = SerialPort1.BytesToRead 'get # of bytes available
    buf(numBytes - 1) As Byte 'allocate a buffer
    br As Int = SerialPort1.Read(buf, 0, numBytes) 'read the bytes
    If br <> numBytes {
        Resize(buf, br) 'resize the buffer
    }
```

at this point store the bytes into a list.  This list can then be processed for messages.